# How to add image to c3.js line chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, c3.js

Hi I am trying to add an image in c3.js line chart x-axis but somehow the image does not show. I can see the image tag in the console but it is not visible in the chart.

my code:
d3.select(".c3-axis-x")

```
  .append("image")
  .attr("class", "footerLogo")
  .attr("xlink:href", "http://upload.smileyswelove.com/uploads/2854/smiley-10225.jpg")
  .attr("width", "70px");
```

[complete fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cu84qtv7/2/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Needs a height attribute as well

```
  .attr("height", "70px")
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cu84qtv7/3/